# Loading after a minute

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing, bandwidth, website

Here is the web site. http://reachourfans.com

when i enter the site, it's loading nothing, and after a minute it's beginning loading the site. I've switched off the Update module, and installed it to another server it's working fine, and in my local server it's working with no problem

as far as the site is working in other server, i think that the cause for the not loading is in the server side.

What can be the cause for the above issue? I'm not so geek in server/administration tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was in the Apache Server, especially in the GZip module, we have unistalled it and again installed and the site is working fluentlty

Answer (score 2):

You can use pingdom[1] to make sure the issue. First you have to identify which part is slow. Server network or the application.

Use a traceroute to makesure network have no delay.

[1] http://www.pingdom.com/a1/

Answer (score 0):

It may be dns-related issue.

When server gets request from some ip it tries to get reverse record (if it is specified in configuration or if there's some place in the code). If it does not works it may cause big delay.

Check that dns is working by running something like `host 209.85.137.147`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have several issues.

- In answer directly to your question. When you do a ping  -a 208.69.148.81, it should be resolving to reachourfans.com, but this isn't the case. I think you need an additional CNAME (need to double check this)
- htaccess file - When you go to the IP address (208.69.148.81), we reach your Unity Content management homepage, this is flawed. It should be the homepage of your main site.... and also you just inherited an additional security issue, as a script kiddie could attempt to exploit it. Take a backup of the htaccess before doing anything.
- The other issue i noticed, you don't have any MX records... so you won't be able to send or recieve any emails.